# ''Hide'' OnClick Event Code Execution

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I have pretty lengthy code that needs to be executed when user presses a specific button.

```
protected void Post(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //1) Code that processes submitted data
    //2) Passess the processed data to SQL DB
    //3) Receives data from DB
    //4) Generates PDF
    //5) Sends the PDF To User

    Response.Redirect("~/SomePage.aspx");
}
```

However,  the code, takes about 6 seconds to execute, which is quite a long time, and while this code is executing, nothing is happening on the screen and redirect only happens after this Event(1-5) has been successfully completed.

**What I would like to know is if its somehow possible to redirect the user ASAP to the desired site and process the data in background?**

If yes, what would I need to use?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Add a loading image to the page which is shown when the user clicks on the button at clientside. This approach is much easier and the user knows that something happens and that he needs to have a little patience.

Comment: You could create a background Task and start the processing there and redirect the user in the same second. This only if you don't want to follow what @TimSchmelter suggested

Comment: How about create a thread just after step 2 gets completed and let the rest of step 3,4,5 do by background process else as @TimSchmelter suggested add a loading/processing image.

Comment: I would personally look in to something like [Rebus](https://github.com/rebus-org/Rebus) to handle and process the message in a separate process that runs as a service.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can go to your next page while inserting all the necessary data as page parameters. Then you can start your process on that page. The process can work in another thread (see [Tasks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd537609(v=vs.110).aspx) / [BackgroundWorker](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/CSASPNETBackgroundWorker-5a0cea51))

- PRO: The user is instantly redirected at the correct page
- CON: Extra code needed for telling the user the operation succeeded or not, What will happen if the process fails?

You could also work with a waiting gif and text stating a process is being run and at the end of the process still going to the new page (as used in several web applications bank etc...)

- PRO: upon having an error, the user can repeat the process by clicking a button instead of re-entering form values
- (From TimSchmelter)Less work for the programmer / Less costs for the client; more intuitive
- CON: user is not instant redirected

Comment: Thank you for suggestion, will definitely check it out.

Comment: Another PRO: much cheaper for the developer to simply add a loading gif and intuitive for the user. Consider that the user doesn't know what  to do on the other page until the process is finished.

Comment: @TimSchmelter, true :D

Comment: Well, it's a survey, I don't think user wants to be waiting for that long, even if there is a gif.

Comment: @RRaymond, that's why I entered both options. The backgroundworker/ task will do that operation for you

Answer (score 0):

```
Thread obj = new Thread(
new ThreadStart(new ThreadStart(() => VoidFuncName(...parameters....)));
obj.IsBackground = true;
obj.Start();
Response.Redirect("~/someaspxsite.aspx");
```

This is what I used. It created a new thread that executes the code. Works flawlessly.